# Graph api not always return exactly who likes posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Graph Api return exactly number of "likes" but not enough for who like that post.

result for print_r:

```
[likes] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Mai Khánh
                        [id] => 100000041712337
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Thinh Truong
                        [id] => 100000273822852
                    )

            )

        [count] => 4
    )
```

Any idea for that ? I found some question nearly similar to mine, but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of two things:

1. The facebook api plays fast and loose with the numbers of likes/comments. Often it is estimated. Look at a post with a high number of comments. As you expand more the number changes. This, as well as conversations with their developers, suggest that the number is not absolute.
2. This could be a paging issue. Make sure you aren't passing any query parameters that would limit your search such as page, limit, offset, or since.